# Properties of object returned by imageinfo in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

In MatLab R2010B, how do I reference fields in the object returned by the function call to imageinfo? I'm

Example of the code:

```
imagePropObj = imageinfo('imageFile.tif');
```

This pops up a window showing the various properties of the image file. Then I try accessing the Width property using

```
imagePropObj.Width
```

but I get the error

```
??? Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imageinfo` returns the handle to the figure. That is not what you want. I assume that you'd actually want to use [IMFINFO](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imfinfo.html), which does return a structure with a field 'Width'.

Comment: Thank you very much! I would have just said 'thanks' but comments must be at least 15 characters long.